# Debugging an assertion with gdb shows weird std::string size

Tags: c++, gdb, assert, coredump

I have a problem with an assertion in a C++ program.

```
HA_Archive & HA_Archive::operator << (const string & str) {
    buffer[wcursor] = HA_TYPE_STRING;
    wcursor++;
    unsigned size = str.size();
    CASSERT((bufferSize > wcursor + size),"buffer exceeds the maximum");
```

CASSERT is a simple assert, and there is the problem.

The program left a core dump that I have debugged with gdb, and I found something strange.

```
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0xb7766424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7766424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb6cd1cb1 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xb6cd33e8 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xb6ccb58c in __assert_fail () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x086c6dbd in HA_Archive::operator<< (this=0xb2610fb8, str=@0xb49e1f08) at HA_Archive.cxx:94
#5  0x0849b4d3 in PortDriver::serialize (this=0xb49e1ed8, ar=@0xb2610fb8) at PortDriver.cxx:624
#6  0x0838ed80 in PortSession::serialize (this=0xb49e1630, ar=@0xb2610fb8) at PortSession/PortSession.h:71

(gdb) frame 4
#4  0x086c6dbd in HA_Archive::operator<< (this=0xb2610fb8, str=@0xb49e1f08) at HA_Archive.cxx:94
94  HA_Archive.cxx: No such file or directory.
    in HA_Archive.cxx
(gdb) print str
$1 = (const string &) @0xb49e1f08: {static npos = 4294967295, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0xb322f9b4 "NOT-SET"}}
(gdb) print wcursor
$2 = 180
(gdb) print bufferSize
$3 = 4096
(gdb) print size
$4 = 171791040
```

Printing the **str** I can see that it has **"NOT-SET"**  and that is OK, but when I print the variable **size** that is **str.size()** the value is huge! Obviously is the cause that make the asserts fails, because bufferSize is 4096 and wcursor is only 180.

I am very far to be and expert in gdb so my first question is if I am doing something wrong whit it. Maybe size is not the real value at runtime?

My second question is: If gdb is showing the correct value of size, why I am seeing correctly the string "NOT-SET" when I print it, but the size is that huge number?

Comment: The size you get may be `(unsigned long)-1` or something like that. It means the size's broken because the memory got corrupted.

Comment: What optimization level are you using when compiling?

Comment: You should post MCVE, otherwise we are just guessing here, problem could be in calling context for example.

Comment: Try to call `str.size()` directly from gdb prompt like this: `(gdb) print str.size()`.

Comment: ForceBru I can't match that number with any thing that have sense like -1 because the size is not always the same, maybe I am wrong.. I don't know. Vaughn  Cato I am using level 2. Slava i can't post MCVE because I can't reproduce the error, it happens some times but i can't define when. ks1322, I cant't print str.size() because the gdb says that I  need a running process to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways this can happen.

The string could really be that size, but the contents could have a nul character at str[7], which would cause GDB to stop printing it out.

Or maybe something has scribbled on your heap and has overwritten the memory location that stores the string's size, so although the contents are still only 7 bytes long the size member has been overwritten with garbage.

Or `str` could just be a dangling reference and the memory pointed to by `_M_p` still contains the string "NOT-SET" but the memory containing the size member has been re-used for something else.

I would try running under valgrind to ensure there are no buffer overruns that might be overwriting the member, or use-after-free errors.

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Sadly I am not able to use Valgrind because it happens only in production (I can't reproduce it), and the program is a turtle running under it. I accepted this answer because I considered that one of the three options is my error. Now I have to find which one. Is there any way to save this at runtime?